# Is it possible for two users to mount the same Shared disk on Time Capsule? (On one Mac.)

Tags: time-capsule, afp, file-sharing

The situation is this; 1 shared Mac Mini with user switching.  If I leave the Shared disk mounted and the other user logs in, they get prompted for Administrator credentials (which disconnects me.)  We both need to be able mount and use the share without disrupting processes running under each user.

Comment: I think the problem may be that automount is trying to reuse /Volumes/Data.  Maybe I could just hard mount it for each user to their own path and stop accessing via Finder.

I'll have to try this tonight unless any one else can test/confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the same thing, without any problems... Do you use user accounts to authenticate the users on the time capsule ? If yes, you should probably configure it to use the airport network. With this, both users will connect with the same "account", and should be able to use the same share concurrently (that works for me)

Here is a screen cap of the setting (sorry, it's in french) :

[image: activating airport password for file share authentication]

Comment: I do use accounts, but I use seperate accounts in order to have private folders as well as the shared.  I'm hoping I can find a solution that allows for this.

Comment: I think you will not be able to do this : the only way to allow this is to have the "shared" folder owned by a group, and the "private" folders owned by their user. But the Time capsule does not support groups management AFAIK...